# how to add cors in the below node js socket io code

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, cors

i am trying to add cors origin as from the client side it is blocking my request , i tried doing the following command but it is showing that it is not a function, can you suggest a method to add cross origin policy to my code

```
const axios = require('axios');
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const socket = require('socket.io');
const io = socket(server)(8000, {
cors: {
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
},
});

.
.
.
.
.

server.listen(8000, () => console.log('server is running on port 8000'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://example.com",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  }
});
```

You don't need to pass port instead provide httpserver. For more details check the [Socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/) documentation.